# Make Sphinx generate reStructuredText pages from Python docstrings

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docstring

I have a free private github repo. I would like to have in a `docs` folder the docstrings turned into rst files.
This is what sphinx does, but generate `html` instead of `rst`.

For all rst files generated this way (let's imagine one rst file per python module), I intend to hyperlink it from the readme to have access to the code documentation this way (without having to rely on github pages, which I have no access to, given I have a free account).

Please, is this possible?
Ideally, I would need a way to tell sphinx `autodoc` extension to generate documentation in rst instead of html, but I haven't found a way for this.

Is there another lib for this?

Thanks for any help,
Bests,

Comment: First it sounds like you want to use [`sphinx.ext.autosummary`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosummary.html) to generate .rst files from docstrings. autodoc then renders the .rst to HTML. Also neither GitHub nor Pages support this. Try readthedocs.org for free hosting and automatic builds of your docs.

Comment: Maybe https://pypi.org/project/sphinxcontrib-restbuilder/ is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed in comment from @mzjn, I used `sphinxcontrib-restbuilder` for this purpose.
Hyperlinks work, this is perfect for my need.

I applied it on the sphinx documentation of a public project of mine, and uploaded it on [this github repo](https://github.com/yohplala/oups-doc-rst) for those willing to have a look.

Click on `index.rst` and follow the read. There do be some glitches.
The API is documented in `api.rst`. This is really this part that is of interest for me.
I think it is nice enough.

[image]